# Indexes and multi column primary keys

Tags: sql, mysql, primary-key, indexing

In a MySQL database I have a table with the following primary key

```
PRIMARY KEY id (invoice, item)
```

In my application I will also frequently be selecting on `item` by itself and less frequently on only `invoice`.  I'm assuming I would benefit from indexes on these columns.

MySQL does not complain when I define the following:

```
INDEX (invoice),
INDEX (item),
PRIMARY KEY id (invoice, item)
```

But I don't see any evidence (using DESCRIBE -- the only way I know how to look) that separate indexes have been established for these two columns.

Are the columns that make up a primary key automatically indexed individually? Is there a better way than DESCRIBE to explore the structure of my table?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. As usual, great information from a really generous community. Answers seem to focus on sorting vs selecting. Are the indexes just as important for selecting? I'll be using select statements that will return between 1 and ~10 rows. In my situation, the order really won't matter.

Comment: indices are more important for selecting when the query returns few rows, and more important for sorting when queries return many rows...   sorting 10 rows is trivial. finding them is hard.  If the query returns the whole table, (or a substantial chunk of it) then finding the rows is not an issue, but sorting that large resultset is...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with the internals of indices on mySql, but on the two database vendor products that I am familiar  with (MsSQL, Oracle)  indices are [Balanced-Tree](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/balanced-trees) (***B-Tree***) structures, whose nodes are organized as a sequenced tuple of the columns the index is defined on (***In the Sequence Defined***) See Note

So, unless mySql does it very differently, (probably not),  any composite index (on more than one column) *can* be useable by any query that needs to filter or sort by a ***subset*** of the columns in the index, as long as the list of columns is compatible, i.e., if the columns, when sequenced the same as the sequenced list of columns in the complete index, is an ordered subset of the complete set of index columns, which starts at the beginning of the actual index sequence, with no gaps except at the end...

In other words, this means that if you have an index on (a,b,c,d)  a query that filters on (a),  (a,b), or (a,b,c)  can also use the index, but a query that needs to filter on (b), or (c), (b,c) or (a, c) will not be able to use the index...

So in your case, if you often need to filter or sort on column ***item*** alone, you need to add another index on that column by itself...

NOTE: Normally, when using the term Balanced tree, it is implied that each node in the tree may have a maximum of two sub-nodes or branches. This is then called a Balanced ***Binary*** tree. Indices in SQL Server are just balanced *non-binary* B-Trees, where the nodes can have more than two sub-nodes or branches. The index optimizer calculates how many branches to allocate to each node based on optimizing performance. The fewer sub-nodes that exist on each node, the taller (height or depth) the tree will be. The optimum number of branches (that maximizes performance in locating a specific record), depends on the number of discreet values of the index attributes within the total data set domain.

Comment: This is exactly how Mysql does it. Here is a ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: @Nikhil,  Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Very simple and clean explanation! It also fits to MySQL implementation. Thanks.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer. The explanation is correct for composite indices, but not for multi-column primary key.

Comment: This does not answer the users question in if using an index on a single column that is also part of the multi primary keys is necessary.

Comment: Yes it does. Read the last sentence. The text prior to that lays the groundwork for understanding the answer. Otherwise, I could have just said "No".

Comment: @CharlesBretana What about inner join ? Which column (a or b or c or d) will be suitable for inner join condition ?

Comment: Joins have nothing to do with it. The presence of, or the usability of an index to support the processing to implement a join is a separate question. You can join on anything, regardless of what indices exist. If an index exists that supports the join processing logic the query optimizer will use it, if not, it will still join, it will just perform a brute force (table-scan) comparison. But whether an index can be used for a join conforms to the same rules as above.... {a}, or {a,b}, or {a,b,c}, or the complete set of join columns, if specified in the join, would allow the index to be used

Answer (score 21):

I personally use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to view and edit the structure of MySQL databases.  It is a web application but it runs well enough on a local web server (I run an instance of apache on my machine for this and phpPgAdmin).

As for the composite key of `(invoice, item)`, it acts like an index for `(invoice, item)` and for `invoice`.  If you want to index by just `item` you have to add that index yourself.  Your PK will be sorted by `invoice` and then by `item` where `invoice` is the same in multiple records.  While the order in a composite PK does not matter for uniqueness enforcement, it does matter for access.

On your table I would use:

```
PRIMARY KEY id (invoice, item), INDEX (item)
```

Comment: thank you for the information and for clear and easy to understand answer, you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: This should be selected as answer as it explains that multi primary key is used like index and uses left prefix, so creating an index with item column is useful and not redundant, while the creating an index for the invoice column would be redundant due to left prefix access.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not that familiar with MySQL, but generally an multiple-column index is equally useful on the first column in the index as an index on that column alone.  The multiple-column index becomes less useful for querying against a single column the further the column appears into the index.

This makes some sense if you think of the multi-column index as a hierarchy.  The first column in the index is the root of the hierarchy, so searching it is just a matter of scanning that first level.  However, in order to scan the second column, the database has to look up the tree for each unique value found in the first column.  This can be costly enough that most optimizers won't bother to look deeply into a multi-column index, instead opting to full-table-scan.

For example, if you have a table as follows:

```
Col1 |Col2 |Col3
----------------
   A |   1 |   Z
   A |   2 |   Y
   A |   2 |   X
   B |   1 |   Z
   B |   2 |   X
```

Assuming you have an index on all three columns, in order, the tree will look something like this:

```
A
+-1
  +-Z
+-2
  +-X
  +-Y
B
+-1
  +-Z
+-2
  +-X
```

Looking for Col1='A' is easy: you only have to look at 2 ordered values.  However, to resolve col3='X', you have to look at all of the values in the 4 bigger buckets, each of which is ordered individually.

Answer (score 4):

To return table index information, you can use:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM <table>;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

To view table information:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Primary keys are indexes, so there's no need to create additional indexes.  You can find out more information about them under the `CREATE TABLE` syntax (there's too much to insert here):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between composite index and composite primary key.
If you have defined a composite index like below

```
INDEX idx(invoice,item)
```

the index wont work if you query based on `item` and you need to add a separate index

```
INDEX itemidx(item)
```

But, if you have defined a composite primary key like below

```
PRIMARY KEY(invoice, item)
```

the index would work if you query based on `item` and no separate index is required.

Working example:

```
mysql>create table test ( col1 int(20), col2 int(20) ) primary key(col1,col2);
mysql>explain select * from test where col2 = 1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   10 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: This answer seems to contradict with the selected answer and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14256/how-is-index-on-composite-primary-key-in-mysql

Comment: This is wrong, incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql auto create an index for composite keys. Depending on your queries, you may have to create separate index for individual column in the composite key.

If you are using mysql workbench, you can manually right click the schema and click on edit to see everything about the table

Answer (score 0):

If your query is using both columns in where clause then you don't need to create a separate index in a composite primary key.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE invoice = 1 and item = 1
```

You are also fine if you want to query with first column only

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE invoice = 1
```

But if you want to query with subsequent columns col2, col3 in composite PK then you would need to create separate indexes on those columns. The following explain query shows the second column does not have a possible key detected by MySQL

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE item = 1
```