# MySql documentation on PRIMAY KEY( param, param.. ) syntax using several params

Tags: mysql

Anybody know where I can find the official MySql documentation on the `PRIMARY KEY( param, param..)` syntax that has several params to create one primary key?

All I could find on google was: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indexes and multi column primary keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048154/indexes-and-multi-column-primary-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY` as part of `CREATE TABLE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: 5.1 is an old version.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is defined in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE commands:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html

Here are some simple examples:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_lines (
    invoice_id int NOT NULL,
    product_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, product_id)
);

ALTER TABLE invoice_lines
ADD PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, product_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the official manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Also note that the order of the keys is important for those who want to use AUTO_INCREMENT and depends on the storage engine used for the table.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643986/3277192