# Usage of foreign key as part of composite key or creating a new key (id)? Which one to use when?

Tags: database-design, composite-primary-key, composite-key

**Both are valid, but which one should be used when?**

**Here's a little example:**

Case of AlarmProfileID as prime key

[image]

Case of composite key consisting of {username and name}

[image]

Comment: *Both are valid, but which one should be used when?* Formally both are valid, this is correct. But they describes two different systems. You have only one system - so you must select those scheme which is adequate to your system.. and it is possible that none of them matches.

Comment: I see what you're saying. In the first case a user can have multiple alarmProfiles with the same name, but in the second case it can't.
Thanks!

Comment: Some years ago I gave this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380909/2270762 when asked when to use composite keys. It is rather long, but thorough. Maybe you find the answer you are looking for in that explanation.